# Storing values from child to parent class

Tags: inheritance, hashmap, abstract-class

I want to know how to store values from child to parent class.

```
public class Question {

private HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> mcqHashMap = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>(); //storing question and options of MCQ
public ArrayList<String> rankingquestion = new ArrayList<String>();
public Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
public ArrayList<String> correctMCQAnswer = new ArrayList<String>(); // will keeps the correct answer of each question
HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> newmcqHashMap;

public HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> getMCQQuestionAnswer() {
    System.out.println("NEW:" + mcqHashMap);
    return this.newmcqHashMap;

}

public void setMCQQuestionAnswer(HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> mcqQuestionAnswer) {
    this.mcqHashMap = mcqQuestionAnswer;
    System.out.println("After setting" + this.mcqHashMap);
    newmcqHashMap = this.mcqHashMap;
}


}


public class MultipleChoiceQuestion extends Question {

String storeMultipleChoiceQuestion;
ArrayList<String> answersMCQ = new ArrayList<String>();
HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> mcqQuestionAnswer = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();


//returns MCQQuestion
public String storeMultipleChoiceQuestion() {
    System.out.println("Enter the Multiple question: ");
    String MultipleChoiceQuestion = scan.nextLine();
    while(MultipleChoiceQuestion.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Null in invalid");
        MultipleChoiceQuestion = scan.nextLine();   

    }
    return MultipleChoiceQuestion;
}

//creates MCQ Questions with mcq options
public void create() {
    String value = storeMultipleChoiceQuestion();
    try {
        System.out.println("Enter the number of choices for your multiple choice question:");
        int numberOfChoices = scan.nextInt();
        scan.nextLine();
        if(numberOfChoices <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Must be greater than 0");
        }
        else {
            for(int i=1; i <= numberOfChoices; i++){
                System.out.println("Enter prompt " + i);
                String Option = scan.nextLine();
                answersMCQ.add(Option);
                while(Option.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println("Null in invalid");
                     Option = scan.nextLine();
                }
                mcqQuestionAnswer.put(value, answersMCQ);
                super.setMCQQuestionAnswer(mcqQuestionAnswer);
                //this.mcqHashMap.put(value, answersMCQ);                   
            }
        }
        }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception thrown! Use integer greater than 0.");
        }
        }
```

upto here its fine...

Now, when I try to access from another child class Survey.

```
public class Survey extends Question implements Serializable {


MultipleChoiceQuestion mcq = new MultipleChoiceQuestion();
public void Display() {

    System.out.println("THis is from get " + this.getMCQQuestionAnswer());
    System.out.println("THis is from get mcqhash" + this.newmcqHashMap);

}
```

`
Doesn't print anything...

I'm sure I am doing wrong somewhere. I also used getter setter in parent class but still no luck. So basically, question will store into mcqHashMap and I want to use the stored mcqHashMap for displaying purpose from Survey class.

Help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: if you say that is does print anything at all, may be `mcqHashMap` is empty at all? it's really hard to tell what is going on from your vague example

Comment: I just edited with more details. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind guys, I figured it out. Thanks! I made protected static instead of protected hashmap. Bad practice but works!

Thanks for the help.